# como alinhar 6 elementos articles em duas fileiras?

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Estou fazendo um site responsivo Mobile Fist, e no media query estou tentando alinhas os articles em duas fileiras são 6 articles, logo abaixo vai estar os codigos:

```css
/* SERVIÇOS*/
.servicos {width: 100%;  text-align: left; padding: 3% 4%;}
.servico {width: 100%; background-color: #fff; text-align: left; border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px; margin-bottom: 3%;}
.servico img {border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0; margin-left: 18%;}
.descriçao {padding: 7%;}
.descriçao a {font-size: 1.5em; color: #130400; font-weight: 700; }
.descriçao h4 {font-size: 1.2em; color: #130400; margin-top: 2%; }
.descriçao p {margin-top: 6%; color: #130400; line-height: 1.5em;}



/* SMALL DEVICE - TABLETS */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px;)  {


}
```

```html
<main class="servicos">
     <article class="servico">
         <a href="#"><img src="img/comprasdeeuipamento.jpg" alt="Campanhas publicitárias"></a>
     <div class="descriçao">
      <a href="#">Treinamento Completo</a>
       <h4>Nos damos um treinamento completo com tudo necessário para abrir uma gelateria</h4>
       <p>também ajudamos a achar preços é marcas ideais para comprar equipamentos.</p>
     </div>
     </article>
     <article class="servico">
         <a href="#"><img src="img/comprasdeeuipamento.jpg" alt="Campanhas publicitárias"></a>
     <div class="descriçao">
      <a href="#">Treinamento Completo</a>
       <h4>Nos damos um treinamento completo com tudo necessário para abrir uma gelateria</h4>
       <p>também ajudamos a achar preços é marcas ideais para comprar equipamentos.</p>
     </div>
     </article>
     <article class="servico">
         <a href="#"><img src="img/comprasdeeuipamento.jpg" alt="Campanhas publicitárias"></a>
     <div class="descriçao">
      <a href="#">Treinamento Completo</a>
       <h4>Nos damos um treinamento completo com tudo necessário para abrir uma gelateria</h4>
       <p>também ajudamos a achar preços é marcas ideais para comprar equipamentos.</p>
     </div>
     </article>
     <article class="servico ser2">
         <a href="#"><img src="img/comprasdeeuipamento.jpg" alt="Campanhas publicitárias"></a>
     <div class="descriçao">
      <a href="#">Treinamento Completo</a>
       <h4>Nos damos um treinamento completo com tudo necessário para abrir uma gelateria</h4>
       <p>também ajudamos a achar preços é marcas ideais para comprar equipamentos.</p>
     </div>
     </article>
     <article class="servico ser2">
         <a href="#"><img src="img/comprasdeeuipamento.jpg" alt="Campanhas publicitárias"></a>
     <div class="descriçao">
      <a href="#">Treinamento Completo</a>
       <h4>Nos damos um treinamento completo com tudo necessário para abrir uma gelateria</h4>
       <p>também ajudamos a achar preços é marcas ideais para comprar equipamentos.</p>
     </div>
     </article>
     <article class="servico ser2">
         <a href="#"><img src="img/comprasdeeuipamento.jpg" alt="Campanhas publicitárias"></a>
     <div class="descriçao">
      <a href="#">Treinamento Completo</a>
       <h4>Nos damos um treinamento completo com tudo necessário para abrir uma gelateria</h4>
       <p>também ajudamos a achar preços é marcas ideais para comprar equipamentos.</p>
     </div>
     </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer isso fazendo com que o tamanho dos elementos `child` seja de `50%` a partir de um determinado ponto usando `media queries`, ou podes fazer isso já implementando diretamente no elemento dando um `width:50%;` e um `max-width:;` para definirmos um limite de tamanho que queiramos que elas tenham, que neste caso será o tamanho desejado que queremos que os artigos tenham em ambientes *desktop*, ou de maiores dimensões de ecrãs. Eis um exemplo abaixo:

```css
/* Shenanigans para dar padding */
.servicos * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.servico {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 300px; /* adiciona tamanho máximo dos elementos */
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px; /* fix para o inline-block */
    background-color: rgba(142, 158, 196, 0.45);
    padding: 3px;
    background-clip: content-box; /* Especifica area pintada do background (box-sizing)*/
}
.servico h4 b {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="servicos">
    <div class="servico">
    <h4>Que Título Fantástico!<b>1</b></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget felis libero..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="servico">
        <h4>Que Título Fantástico!<b>2</b></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget felis libero..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="servico">
        <h4>Que Título Fantástico!<b>3</b></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget felis libero..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="servico">
        <h4>Que Título Fantástico!<b>4</b></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget felis libero..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="servico">
        <h4>Que Título Fantástico!<b>5</b></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget felis libero..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="servico">
        <h4>Que Título Fantástico!<b>6</b></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget felis libero..</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou podes fazer utilizando [Multiple Columns](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp), como neste [exemplo no jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/dmopckm7/), mas que troca a ordem de como os elementos são apresentados. Em vez de serem horizontalmente, a contagem se torna verticalmente como podes ver no link desse mesmo exemplo.

Comment: Valeu, você me ajudou muito!